# How to scan pdf files in the system and alert number of pdf files using swift ?

Tags: ios, swift

I am Fresher .I don't know how to scan pdf files in the system and alert number of pdf files using swift.

Comment: You can't scan files in system in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this :

```
var counter:Int=0
let alertController = UIAlertController()
let file = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let enumer:NSDirectoryEnumerator = file.enumeratorAtPath(folderPath)

while let element = enumer?.nextObject() as? String {
    if element.hasSuffix("pdf") { 
       counter++
    }
}
alertController(title: "Number of PDF Files", message:"\(counter)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: In folder path, what path i have to give ??

Comment: In `let enumer:NSDirectoryEnumerator = file.enumeratorAtPath(folderPath)` replace folderPath with a string giving the path to the folder which contains the pdf files. Check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:). Also, please accept the answer if I helped! :)